# Heat transfer coefficient in a Module Baseplate

Tags: power-electronics, temperature, heat, thermal, heatsink

Today, for example in a power IGBT module cooled by a heatsink, it has been found that the heat transfer coefficient (htc) distribution may not be uniform across the bottom surface of the module baseplate. If it is going to be non-uniform, do you have any images for the distribution? I think that the parameter htc directly under chips heated up must be the highest due to the largest temperature available in the whole baseplate. And as we get far from this hot region of the baseplate, the parameter htc will be reduced due to lower temperatures. What do you think?
The screenshot below shows a power module mounted on the heatsink that may have a fluid flow among its plate fins.
[image]

Comment: there are various formulae for thermal resistance and sponge copper water cooled gives the optimal heat transfer for water flow vs power density transfer , and optimal is probably only avail to researchers such as my colleague

Comment: Cross posted : https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/489948/207455